# PHP require_once not working in my code

Tags: php

this is probably a basic question about php, but I can't figure out how to solve it.

Well, I have a file called globals.php

```
<?php
$DATA = array(
    'first' => 'LOL',
    'second' => 'Whatever'
);
?>
```

And I also have another file (omg.php) with the following function:

```
<?php

require_once('globals.php');

function print_text_omg($selector = 0){
global $DATA; //added this line of code. NOW IT WORKS
$var = '';
if($selector == 0){
    $var = '';
}else{
    $var = 'Hi. ';
}

//$DATA is a variable from globals.php that is supposed to be declared in require_once('globals.php');
//$var is a variable inside the function print_text_omg
//I am trying to concatenate string $var with the string $DATA['first']

$finaltext = $var.$DATA['first'];
echo $finaltext;
}
?>
```

Then, in main.php I have this:

```
<?php 
include('omg.php');
print_text_omg();
print_text_omg(1);
?>
```

This should print something like:

```
//LOL
//Hi. LOL
```

Instead, I have this warning:

Notice: Undefined variable: DATA in ...

Which is the part of `$finaltext = $var.$DATA['first'];`

**UPDATE**

Thanks to user Casimir et Hippolyte' suggestion, I've edited my function and it works now. Added the line that worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because `$DATA` isn't in the scope of your function.

To make `$DATA` available inside your function, you must pass it as a  parameter to the function or define `$DATA` as a global variable.

The problem isn't related to `require_once`.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: THANK YOU, I've added `global $DATA;` to my function and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @mgXD-2: be careful, using globals denotes a conception problem (most of the time) and is considered as a bad practice *(The good practice is to allow the access to an information only to concerned elements)*. It is better to add a parameter to your function, or to build a class where `$DATA` is a static variable and your function a method of the class. (but I think you will test this last way later).

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct, first I can't find where did you declare `$var` (maybe it should be an object of some class?) and also `$var` doesn't contain the $DATA array, and for last,  `.` operator in php is for concatenate strings, for object navigation is `->` operator

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared the variable `$var`, plus `.` is php's concatenation operator. Try changing your code to this

`$finaltext = $DATA['first']`;